# How to generate RPC style WSDL in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl, axis

I'd like to generate RPC style WSDL when developing my JAX web service

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use = Use.ENCODED)
public class SoapTest {
    @WebMethod
    public int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Even though it looks OK, Eclipse always generates `document/literal` wsdl, no matter what my `@SOAPBinding` looks like.

I generate WSDL like this:

> New -> Web Service -> [Choosing SoapTest class, choosing **Apache
>   AXIS**] -> Finish

I've also tried to create interface SoapTest and implementation class SoapTestImpl (like I've learned from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/)) with no luck.

I use Eclipse Mars, Apache Axis.